# Changing 3 column 4 row HTML table to Divs

Tags: html

I basically have my page layout, however I have put my main content in a table in my main div. I need to change this up so I no longer have a table, instead have it all in divs. Below is my code for my main div and screenshot of the design, help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
<div id="mainDiv">
<h1>Places to go</h1>
<div id="divBreak"></div>
<table id="mainTable" rules="ROWS" frame="HSIDES">
<tr>
<td id="table1"><strong>Leeds Castle</strong><br>
Considered one of the most romantic castles in England, this historic site was originally       the stately home of the Saxon royal family during the reign of Ethelbert IV in 856-860.</td>
<td id="table2"><img class="imageTable" src="./images/leeds.jpg" alt="leeds"      name="imageTable"></td>
<td id="columnRight" rowspan="4"><strong>Welcome to Maidstone</strong><br>
Maidstone is the county town of Kent, England, 32 miles (51 km) south-east of London. The   River Medway runs through the centre of the town linking Maidstone to Rochester and the Thames   Estuary. Historically, the river was a source and route for much of the town's trade.   Maidstone was the centre of the agricultural county of Kent, known as the Garden of England.     There is evidence of a settlement in the area dating back to beyond the Stone Age. The town is   within the borough of Maidstone. In 2001, the town had a population of 75,070. Maidstone's    economy has changed over the years from being involved in heavy industry, to more light and    service industries.<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<strong>Where we are</strong> <img src="./images/maidstone_map.gif" alt="Maidstone Map">    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="table3"><strong>Mote Park</strong><br>
Maidstone's largest park, is set in 450 acres of historic parkland. Within walking  distance of Maidstone town centre it offers a pleasant and relaxing enviroment, making it a  great place to spend the day.</td>
<td id="table4"><img class="imageTable" src="./images/mote.jpg" alt="Mote Park"   name="imageTable"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="table5"><strong>History Museum</strong><br>
Our exceptional Museum is housed in a charming Elizabethan Manor House, in the centre of  Maidstone - Kent's County Town. Each gallery will fascinate and surprise; with a wealth of  exhibits and objects to see and enjoy as well as regular storytelling and children's holiday  activities. Entry to our Museum is Free!</td>
<td id="table6"><img class="imageTable" src="./images/museum.jpg" alt="Maidstone Museum"   name="imageTable"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="table7"><strong>River Boat</strong><br>
The Kentish Lady river boat offers a unique experience of the River Medway from a 1 hour  trip to 3 hour cruises and is also the perfect setting for a private party.</td>
<td id="table8"><img class="imageTable" src="./images/boat.jpg" alt="Boat"  name="imageTable"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

divs are block elements and naturally display one below the other (vertically) as opposed to inline elements like spans that display one after each other horizontally. 
Knowing that you can alter this default behavior easily. This is a very simple 5 minute tutorial that will show you how to create table like display with divs http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ .